# Run MySQL Service using Node.js on CentOS 7 Server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, centos, mariadb

I have Two VM, both have CentOS 7 Server.

In first VM (192.168.1.150) I have **Node.js v6.3.0**

In my second VM (192.168.1.151) I have **MariaDB v5.5.47**

On my first VM (192.168.1.150) I have one **test_mysql.js** file, code is below mentioned.

```
var _mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = _mysql.createConnection({
        host : '192.168.1.151',
        user : 'root',
        password : 'password',
    port : '3306'
    });

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error>>>>>' + err.stack);
    }

  console.log('Connected as id>>>>>>' + connection.threadId);
  var _conn = connection.threadId;
  if(_conn == null)
  {
    console.log('Not Connected');
    connection.end();
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Connected');
    connection.end();
    return;
  }
});
```

When I run this js file using **node test_mysql.js** command It run successfully.
I am able to connect to mysql.

But I want check mysql service is not running or not on server (192.168.1.151). If service is not running then I want to run mysql service using above test_mysql.js.

Comment: systemd, love it or hate it is perfectly well equipped to handle this task. You don't need to duplicate it withi node.js (which is perfectly ill equipped to handle this task)

Comment: @e4c5 you mean to say, using systemd i can achieve this task.

Comment: systemd is already doing it for you!

Comment: @e4c5 I don't know about systemd. You want to say that If my service is go down with any reason So systemd automatically start my service? If yes so please guide me for this.

Comment: You can also use `simple-ssh` and check the service status